# Insert field in object while performing sorting on a list of objects in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, object

I have list of dictionaries

```
rows = [
  {'name': 'someone1', 'score': 20},
  {'name': 'someone2', 'score': 90},
  {'name': 'someone3', 'score': 60},
]
```

I want to add another field rank based on score. currently I am doing this in multiple steps.

```
# Step 1: sort it
rows_sorted = sorted(rows, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)
# Step 2: add rank field
[row.setdefault('rank', idx) for idx, row in enumerate(rows_sorted, start=1)]
```

So now my required output is in rows_sorted which is like

```
[{'name': 'someone2', 'score': 90, 'rank': 1},
 {'name': 'someone3', 'score': 60, 'rank': 2},
 {'name': 'someone1', 'score': 20, 'rank': 3}]
```

Is there any way to do this in a single step?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the output?

Comment: @Neob91: order will not matter as I am interested in rank field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
rows = [
    dict(row, rank=idx + 1)
    for idx, row in enumerate(sorted(rows, key=lambda x: -x['score']))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
all_scores = sorted([k['score'] for k in rows], reverse = True)
for i in rows:
    i['rank'] = all_scores.index(i['score'])+1
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
>>> rows
[{'name': 'someone1', 'score': 20, 'rank': 3}, {'name': 'someone2', 'score': 90, 'rank': 1}, {'name': 'someone3', 'score': 60, 'rank': 2}]
```

Comment: On the first line, you're unnecessarily iterating twice over the list of rows. A generator expression ought to fix that.